# Grails Audit-Logging Plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, auditing, audit-logging

I use grails audit plugin for logging any domain data change

I am doing simple test to test out this plugin. Inserting/Updating grails form. My update failed with data out of bound. That save was failed, but still auditLog recorded that data in the table. How do I prevent that.

Comment: Can you show a sample about what and how are you testing?

Comment: I have a form with fields. (domain class seller) 1. name 2. address 3. latitude 4. longitude. Latitude and Longitude has got decimal(9,6) data type. When i put some junk value say -27000.232323 grails form will give me validation error. But the audit log table will save that event with new_value as -27000.232323 which did not got stored in seller table in database.How do i prevent it to store in audit log table if my validation fails. @dmahapatro